# netty sever-to-server data streams

Tags: java, sockets, ipc, netty

I have two Java [netty](https://netty.io/) servers that need to pass lots of messages between themselves fairly frequently and I want it to happen fairly promptly.

I need a TCP socket between the two servers that I can send these messages over.

These messages are already-packed byte[] arrays and are self-contained.

The servers are currently both running HTTP interfaces.

What is the best way to do this?

For example, websockets might be a good fit yet I am unable to find any websocket client examples in netty..

I'm a netty newbie so would need some strong simple examples.  It surely can't be so hard?!

Comment: Are you going to use the 3.x.x or 4.x.x version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned HTTP, you could look at the [HttpStaticFileServer](http://static.netty.io/3.5/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/file/package-summary.html) in [the examples](https://netty.io/Documentation/WebHome).

When established, a TCP connection is a `Channel`. To send your messages, you need to write them to a `ChannelBuffer` and call [channel.write](http://static.netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/Channel.html#write%28java.lang.Object%29).

Of course, this does not cover message borders. The `Telnet` example shows a case, where the messages are delimited by the newline character.

Comment: If it doesn't look appropriate, please describe in more detail what you are searching for.

Comment: how to do basic message passing over a socket between to servers.

Comment: Netty doesn't seem to really advocate any communication protocol over the other. You need to decide that yourself.

Comment: the downvote wasn't me.  The doing-your-own-delimiters thing looks like the way to go.